# Ant Design & Webpack not loading css

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd

I've got a React project using Antd and webpack as I wanted to use css modules, however unfortunately this is impacting Antd and I'm way out of my depth to understand how to resolve this.

In my webpack config, I have the following loader:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      require.resolve('style-loader'),
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
        },
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            autoprefixer({
              browsers: [
                '>1%',
                'last 4 versions',
                'Firefox ESR',
                'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
              ],
              flexbox: 'no-2009',
            }),
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

I can confirm that this is working for my own styled elements, but Antd component s are unstyled.

In my App.js, I am importing the antd.css file, however when bundled, it applies the css modules to the antd.css.  This obviously causes a problem as the Antd components haven't had their class names changed.

Can anyone guide me through how to resolve this please?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by adding the @import '~antd/dist/antd.css'; to your css file. However I am also looking for a solution by making the changes in webpack.config